# JavaScript: How can I wrap every word in a string with a span tag containing a unique id?

Tags: javascript, replace

Using Javascript, I want to take the content of a string and wrap every single word with a set of `<span>` tags. Each span tag will have a unique ID attribute that I'll generate. If a word is already encased in a span tag with an id, leave it alone. If it has a span tag without an id, I need to put an id in the span.

So, the following:

```
this is <b>a</b> <span>bunch</span> of <span id="aopksd"><i>text</i></span>
```

Becomes:

```
<span id="dwdkwkd">this</span> <span id="zdkdokw">is</span> <span id="rrrsass"><b>a</b></span> <span id="lwokdw">bunch</span> <span id="poeokf">of</span> <span id="aopksd"><i>text</i></span>
```

Ideas on the best way to accomplish this? I'm doing it server-side in node.js. I prefer a non-jquery method.

EDIT:
The id is something I will generate on the server. I just used placeholder fake ids for now. I will use my own globally unique id.

Comment: how will you get the id?

Comment: @jcolebrand see my edit about the id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, but you might have to inspect the parameter a if you want to make a special treatment for your word already in html tag :

```
var str = "Bonjour, je m'appelle Francis et je suis le plus bel homme du monde​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​";
var regex = /\S+/g;

var id = 0;

var result = str.replace(regex, function(a) {
    return "<span id=" + (++id) + ">" + a + "</span>";
});​​​​​​​​​​

alert(result);
```

live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/NtNtj/

EDIT: If you don't want to overwrite existing ID, you can try this

```
var str = "Bonjour, je m'appelle <b>Francis</b> et <span id=\"existing\">je</span> suis le plus bel homme du monde";
var regex = /(<.+?<\/.+?>|\S+)/g;

var id = 0;

var result = str.replace(regex, function(a) {

    var m = (/<(\w+)([^>]*)>([^<]*)<\/\w+>/).exec(a);

    if (m !== null && m[1] === "span" && m[2].test(/id=/)) 
        return a;

    return "<span id=" + (++id) + ">" + a + "</span>";
});

console.log(result);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NtNtj/8/

EDIT: If you can have multiple word in a tag like  and you still want to wrap each word in between, you can call recursively the replace function with the value inside the tag as so :

```
var str = "Bonjour, <b>je m'appelle Francis</b> et <span id=\"existing\">je</span> suis le plus bel homme du monde";
var regex = /(<.+?<\/.+?>|\S+)/g;

var id = 0;

var result = str.replace(regex, function(a) {

    var m = (/<(\w+)([^>]*)>([^<]*)<\/\w+>/).exec(a);

    if (m !== null && m[1] === "span" && m[2].test(/id=/)) 
        return a;

    if (m !== null)
        return "<" + m[1] + m[2] + ">" + m[3].replace(regex, arguments.callee) + "</" + m[1] + ">";

    return "<span id=" + (++id) + ">" + a + "</span>";
});

console.log(result);
```

live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/francisfortier/NtNtj/9/

Comment: I didn't think you could have numeric IDs. I don't know why I thought that. However, if he wants to have them have "more anonymous ids" there's always the idea of concat'ing them with another value, then running SHA or MD5 or something hashes, and only getting the last 6 or 8 places.

Comment: @jcolebrand the content of the id is irrelevant in this case. It's going to be used outside of a browser as a special GUID.

Comment: @francis yes, that's similar to what I was testing. The harder part (like you say) is dealing with words already inside of tags.

Comment: So do you want to treat existing HTML wrapped elements as valid or do you want to wrap every non-HTML-tag string?

Comment: @jcolebrand existing spans that already have an id are valid and don't need to be changed.  I will be saving this to a database and allowing it to be read from the database, be edited, have spans with IDs assigned to all words that don't already have them, and be saved to the db again. See my original example, that should cover that case and those that have other html tags like `<b>`, etc.

Comment: so what about `<b>this is many words</b>` .. are you skipping it, taking just that node, or the individual words inside it? Is the only criteria to skip span's with IDs? What about div's around words?

Comment: @jcolebrand that would become: `<b><span id="bla">this</span> <span id="foo">is</span> <span id="boo">many</span> <span id="moo">words</span></b>`

Comment: have a look at my second EDIT