# How to get a word under a cursor without wrapping every word with <span> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am currently working on a Chrome Extension that requires a way to acquire the word under the cursor. One common solution I found is to wrap every single word in the html with  tags. However, doing this will strip out any previous HTML and thus remove all the styles and hyperlinks. I used the following code snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9384819/3014680) to recursively add span to every word in *str*, but there are still many cases where it fails when different formatting appears on webpages.

```
var regex = /(\(*<.+?<\/.+?>|\S+)/g;
var spannedStr = str.replace(regex, function(a) {
    var m = (/<(\w+)([^>]*)>([^<]*)<\/\w+>/).exec(a);
    if (m !== null) {
        return "<" + m[1] + m[2] + ">" + m[3].replace(regex, arguments.callee) + "</" + m[1] + ">";
    }
    return "<span class = \"toTranslate\">" + a + "</span>";
});
```

I looked at some other Chrome Extensions, and one of them seemed to have been able to retrieve the word under the cursor without injecting the span tag to every word in the html. My question is: is there another way to find the word under the cursor? Or is there a better way to wrap the words in spans that does not interfere with the original html styles and hyperlinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the top-voted (rather than accepted) answer on this question - I think it may head you in a working direction: [How to get a word under cursor using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444430/how-to-get-a-word-under-cursor-using-javascript?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks! I read through that question before but I missed that answer.